# Make error in OPENCV installation

Tags: linux, opencv

I was trying to install opencv in linux mint. I run the cmake command in the opencv folder.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

But i get the some errors related to pango while running make command in the release folder :

```
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_attr_font_features_new'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_renderer_set_alpha'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_layout_get_serial'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_attr_background_alpha_new'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_layout_get_log_attrs_readonly'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_fc_font_map_config_changed'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_renderer_get_alpha'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined reference to `pango_attr_foreground_alpha_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/build.make:129: recipe for target 'bin/opencv_test_highgui' failed
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_test_highgui] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7412: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to work on virtual enviroment restart with $ mkvirtualenv cv -p python2

Comment: I've installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper using pip, but it says mkvirtualenv command not found

Comment: I dont know your guide but you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/)

Comment: it worked just fine .... i have even setup virtutal environment cv. But problem still remains, while running make -j4, same error occurs.

Comment: Before make command run make clean and run make instead of make -j4

Comment: I did that too. i ran make clean and then make. didn't work